# NodeJS EventEmitter not firing

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I'm working on a class, `WorkflowParent`, that is both an `EventEmitter` and has child properties of type `EventEmitter`.

I'd like the class to intercept some events from its child properties and re-emit them with different event names.

It seems like I'm doing it right, but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var awsswf = require('aws-swf');
var swf = awsswf.createClient();
var util = require('util');

function WorkflowParent(){
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    var me = this;

    //Create decider object
    me.decider = new awsswf.Decider({}); // <---- THIS IS AN EventEmitter

    //Emit events from `decider` and `actor` objects
    ['poll'].forEach(function(eventName){
        me.decider.on(eventName, function(event){
            console.log('decider event "'+eventName+'"', event); // <---- THIS IS EXECUTED
            var attached = me.emit(eventName+'.decider', event); // emit "poll.decider" event
            console.log('attached to poll.decider event?', attached); // <---- THIS IS `false`
        });
    });

}

util.inherits(WorkflowParent, EventEmitter);

WorkflowParent.prototype.start = function(){
    this.on('poll.decider', function(event){
        console.log('poll.decider event triggered!'); // <---- THIS NEVER RUNS
    });
    this.decider.start();
};


module.exports = new WorkflowParent();
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you can't use a property named `domain` in a class that inherits from `EventEmitter`. I renamed `me.domain` to `me._domain` and it worked.

Found details of this bug here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3922

> As noted in the bug, **anything with a domain property** that is also an
>   EventEmitter is going to have this conflict.